# How to pass state into Parent?

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I am fairly new to React, and I am making a small single page application, and I am trying to figure out how to pass the employee ID to the parent.

So there is an issue here, which I already know.... but trying to figure out a solution.

There will be 3 screens first starts with the ID.

When I have it as the code listed below, everytime I type, the state rerenders, however it DOES work. It just really annoying to type.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Body,
  Content,
  Item,
  Input,
  Icon,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'native-base';

export default function App() {
  const [id, setId] = useState('');

  const IdScreen = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Enter your Employee ID</Text>
        <Item rounded style={styles.textBox}>
          <Icon type='Ionicons' name='person' style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
          <Input
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setId(text);
            }}
            value={id}
          />
        </Item>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Body>
          <Title>Employee Enroll</Title>
        </Body>
      </Header>
      <Content>
        <IdScreen />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

If I make this change... the typing part is fine, but when I go to push this to the API, it wont be readable.

```
const IdScreen = () => {
   const [id, setId] = useState('');
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Enter your Employee ID</Text>
        <Item rounded style={styles.textBox}>
          <Icon type='Ionicons' name='person' style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
          <Input
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setId(text);
            }}
            value={id}
          />
        </Item>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

I am looking for a way to type in the person ID, then save that state to the main function so that I can use that variable later.

I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take the `IdScreen` component out of the `App` component (You should have your components in different files), then if you want to pass the id from `IdScreen` to `App` you need to lift up the state. In order to do that you will need to the following:

Put this `const [id, setId] = useState('');` only in the `App` component, then pass the `setId` function to the `IdScreen` component as a props, like this:

`<IdScreen id={id} setId={setId} />`

Then in your `IdScreen` component you can use the setter function and the value as props, like this:

`props.id` and `props.setId`